# Linq query to Get Data between two Dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

The date and time are saved as : 1397/06/10 13:55:49

Linq query is :

```
var showFamily = (from b in database.tbl_kharidnaghdi

                          join u in database.tbl_Customer on b.CustomerID_FK equals u.CustomerID
                          join c in database.tbl_User on u.UserID_FK equals c.UserID
                          orderby b.KharidnaghdiID descending

                          where u.UserID_FK == userid
                            && txtFamily.Text.Contains(u.Family)
                            &&string.Compare(b.Date, txtDate1.Text) <= 0  
                            && string.Compare(b.Date, txtDate2.Text) >= 0
                          select new
                          {
                              u.Name,
                              u.Family,
                              u.Mobile,
                              u.Price,
                              u.CustomerID,
                              b.KharidnaghdiID,
                              b.EtebarHadiye,
                              b.Cashier,
                              b.Date,
                          }).ToList();
        grdShowListUser.DataSourceID = null;
        grdShowListUser.DataSource = showFamily;
```

I think that the date should be separated from the clock like this : 1397/06/10

Comment: why string.Compare. Convert the texts first

Comment: You need to treat both dates as `DateTime` instance and compare them using `CompareTo`.

Comment: That's right, but I do not know how to do it

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto That's right, but I do not know how to do it

Comment: Use `DateTime` variable like `DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate1.Text, "date_format_here")`, then you can do `b.Date.CompareTo(date1) <= 0` inside LINQ query (do the same with other date textbox).

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to compare date values, it is necessary to convert them using `DateTime.ParseExact()` method from `Text` property of textboxes (which is `string` property) and use `CompareTo()` to compare between them:

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate1.Text, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate2.Text, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var showFamily = (from b in database.tbl_kharidnaghdi
                  join u in database.tbl_Customer on b.CustomerID_FK equals u.CustomerID
                  join c in database.tbl_User on u.UserID_FK equals c.UserID
                  orderby b.KharidnaghdiID descending
                  where u.UserID_FK == userid
                  && txtFamily.Text.Contains(u.Family)
                  && b.Date.CompareTo(date1.Date) <= 0 // date comparison here
                  && b.Date.CompareTo(date2.Date) >= 0
                  select new
                  {
                      u.Name,
                      u.Family,
                      u.Mobile,
                      u.Price,
                      u.CustomerID,
                      b.KharidnaghdiID,
                      b.EtebarHadiye,
                      b.Cashier,
                      b.Date,
                  }).ToList();
```

Note that if you're using LINQ to Entities, the `Date` property may not supported, you can use [`DbFunctions.TruncateTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx) or project it to LINQ to Objects with `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` as alternative.

Comment: you need to capitalize the months: `yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss`

Comment: I think the OP missed the comparison. It should be Date >= Date1 && Date <= Date2, not  Date <= Date1 && Date >= Date2, otherwise it will always yield false. Of course, given Date1 >= Date2.

Comment: this code is error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" my data in database format is 1397/06/10 13:55:49 but format fill txtdate is 1397/06/10

Comment: Then you should adjust `ParseExact` for date-only value like `DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate1.Text, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto when format string change to "yyyy/dd/MM" data1 is:8/6/1397 while I fill txtdate1 : 1397/06/08 ===>var showFamily is NULL

Answer (score 0):

data in database is 1397/06/10 13:55:49
data in txtdate is 1397/06/10

I am assuming 1397 is the year (yyyy), 06 is the month (MM) and 10 is the day (dd). And data in your Db is also in string format

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate1.Text, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate2.Text, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


var showFamily = (from b in database.tbl_kharidnaghdi
                  join u in database.tbl_Customer on b.CustomerID_FK equals u.CustomerID
                  join c in database.tbl_User on u.UserID_FK equals c.UserID
                  orderby b.KharidnaghdiID descending
                  where u.UserID_FK == userid
                  && txtFamily.Text.Contains(u.Family)
                  && DateTime.ParseExact(b.Date, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < date1
                  && DateTime.ParseExact(b.Date, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >= date2
                  select new
                  {
                      u.Name,
                      u.Family,
                      u.Mobile,
                      u.Price,
                      u.CustomerID,
                      b.KharidnaghdiID,
                      b.EtebarHadiye,
                      b.Cashier,
                      b.Date,
                  }).ToList();
```

Note: If the result is coming null, then please alter the greater than, less **than condition and check**